# Laravel form request: Change data after validation

Tags: laravel, validation

How do I change data after validation?

The below code will not result in `phone` having spaces removed in `$request->validated()` but it is in `$request`.

My form request:

```
class StoreUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'phone' => ['required', 'string']
        ];
    }

    public function passedValidation()
    {
        $this->merge(['phone' => str_replace(' ', '', $this->get('phone'))]);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
$validated = $request->validated();
$user = Customer::create($validated);
```

Should I use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests instead and Joe would I use it?

Comment: I think your approach is perfectly fine; validate your input, and if valid, remove any extra spaces. I use a similar approach for dates ranges; validate a date in `Y-m-d` format, then add `00:00:00` or `23:59:59` after validation. Sidenote though, your validation doesn't really work for phone numbers; I could still enter something like `'This is my phone number'` and it would be valid. Phone numbers _can_ include letters, like `1-800-FOR-HELP`, so maybe something like the Alpha-Dash rule: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-alpha-dash, which is `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `-`, `_` no spacees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom cast.

The `get` method is responsible for transforming a raw value from the database into a cast value, while the `set` method should transform a cast value into a raw value that can be stored in the database.

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Casts;
 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;
 
class Phone implements CastsAttributes
{
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return $value;
    }
 
    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return str_replace(' ', '', $value);
    }
}
```

And in your model

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use App\Casts\Phone;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'phone' => Phone::class,
    ];
}
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to use the validated data and you can still access and use the original request data after the validation and do any data manipulation you like,

the `$validated` data only has the fields you pass into, so depending on the situation, you may or may not want to use it.

you have different ways to do it

```
public function storeRequest(Request $request) {

    // validation return 422 on failure
    $validated = $request->validate( [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email:filter|max:255|unique:users',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'some_data' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    // Validation fine, can still access the original request
    $request->merge(['phone' => str_replace(' ', '', $request->input('phone'))]);

    // use original request and remove some data
    $user = Customer::create( $request->except('some_data') );

    //or pick some data from original request
    $user = Customer::create( $request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone') );

    // or use the validated data and update the phone value
    $validated['phone'] = str_replace(' ', '', $validated['phone'] ); // or str_replace(' ', '', $request->input('phone') )
    $user = Customer::create( $validated );

}
```